# Does Java has a long term plan to unify Primitive Data Types and Object Data Types? How?

Tags: java, object, primitive

I think I have read some relevant discussions about Java is going to unify primitive and object data types.

Does anyone know the progress? Is it possible at all? I mean you can still keep the benefits of primitive data types after the unification?

Update:

A relevant discussion is here: [no more primitive data types in Java (JDK 10+). What do you think?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.programmer/gsZbcTys6L4)

Answer (score 1):

Scala is the current answer for having a richer type system like this.

Note that primitives are not nullable and have a default value of zero, while objects have a default value of null.  How would your code break if some values were neither true or false, but null instead?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me primitives would just be translated into objects behind the scenes, perhaps by the compiler, although older byte-code would have to still be supported. We wouldn't be able to go the other way due to nulls. For example:

```
int x;
```

Would be interpreted as:

```
Integer x = new Integer(0);
```

Functionality is sort of in place to do some of this automaticallyy. Right now you can do:

```
Integer x = 0;
```

This is the "autoboxing" functionality that was recently introduced.

I'm personally not all that thrilled by this if that's the approach. It will just reduce some syntactic sugar. It would also potentially result in collisions:

```
void myFunc(Integer i) { ; }
void myFunc(int I) { ; }
```

I guess they could wrap primitives into something that extends Integer to avoid this, but that seems even more complicated.